# Почему объявление функции не перезаписывает одноимённую переменную?

Tags: javascript

Обычно попытка объявить функцию *x* после одноимённой переменной вызывает ошибку.

```
var x = 1; // или без присваивания - одинаково.
function x () {console.log('hw')}; // Identifier 'x' has already been declared
```

Когда же я объявляю функцию *x* внутри самовызывающейся функции, ошибка не появляется.

```js
(function() {
  var x;

  function x() {};
  console.log(typeof x); // function 
  x = 1;
  console.log(typeof x); // number
})()
```

А теперь присвоим переменной значение до объявления функции: *x* не перезаписана.

```js
(function() {
  var x;
  x = 1;

  function x() {};
  console.log(typeof x); // number
})()
```

Объясните, почему столько вариантов?

Comment: declaration hoisting

Comment: все зависит от браузера и как именно ты запускаешь, например в консоли или в скрипте

Comment: первый пример с _Identifier 'x' has already been declared_ - не воспроизводится

Comment: @Grundy Оказывается, да (
Это есть на "codesandbox", но нет в консоли браузера.

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo, возможно в песочнице код проходит дополнительную обработку либо проверку.